# TI-83 Plus: Store commonly used functions for easy access?

Tags: calculator

Is there a way to store commonly used formulas for easy access? I use nCr and nPr constantly and every time I use them I have to hit:

For nCr: `[2nd][0 (for CATALOG)][LOG (for N)][Down arrow]`

For nPr: `[MATH][Right][Right][Right][Down]`

Any simpler way to access these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could make a program that would ask for input. 
create a new program by clicking [PRGM] then scroll left to new click [enter] type name NCR then click [enter] again

now click [PRGM] 
scroll right once then click prompt then enter 'a'

now click [PRGM] 
scroll right once then click prompt then enter 'b'

now click [PRGM] 
scroll right once then click disp then enter 'a' [math] scroll right 3 times then click [3]

now enter 'b'

"----------------------------"

to run this click [PRGM]
then click NCR

then enter in a and b value

Comment: Thanks. I wish there was an easier way but this definitely saves me some time.